# vscode code runner: excute codes in external terminal and pause it

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221544/how-to-make-code-runner-run-in-external-terminal-command-prompt)

My intention is

1. to make code run in external terminal
2. to pause that terminal so I can see the result.

Original code-runner setting which runs code in the integrated terminal was

```
"code-runner.executorMap":{  
       "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
       ...  
}
```

I've managed to make codes run in external terminal using this code:

```
"code-runner.executorMap":{  
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && start $fileNameWithoutExt.exe",  
     ...  
}
```

But the terminal disappears so quickly that I can't see the result.
I've tried the fourth answer on the link above:

```
"c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && Start pwsh -Command  \"& {.\\$fileNameWithoutExt.exe; pause}\"",
```

but it doesn't work for me as vscode says: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Command'.

I also tried

```
"c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && start $fileNameWithoutExt.exe && pause",
```

but external terminal still disappears and "pause" makes integrated terminal to pause.
Then I tried

```
"c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && start cmd /k $fileNameWithoutExt.exe"
```

I thought "start cmd" opens new command prompt and "/k" would let it continue.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)

It still doesn't work and vscode says: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument `hw3.exe`. (hw3 is the name of my file)

I know there is `code-runner:run` in terminal- whether to run code in integrated terminal setting in `Files>Preferences>Settings>User` but there are several folders in my workspace and I intend to run code in external terminal for this specific folder only. So I keep that setting checked and working with **settings.json** which is unique to this folder.

Thanks for your time and stay safe!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    "code-runner.executorMap":{
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -O2 -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && start cmd \"/k ; $fileNameWithoutExt\""
    },
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer works for cpp and after changing "cpp" to "c" it works for c as well

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer cannot let me just click once to exit the cmd.

(I think it's a little annoying.)

I think use "/c" with "&pause" is better.

(Actually, we just need one "&" and I don't know why :P)

---

The most comfortable version I think is as follows:

```
"c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && start cmd \"/c ; $fileNameWithoutExt &pause\"",
```